# Repeat rows in a dataframe based on a condition in R

Tags: r, scaling

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
STAND Plot1 X    DBH   Spec   HT              NOTES
1   TEN YEAR VAR RET     1 s   1.25    ASH   NA                   
2   TEN YEAR VAR RET     1 s   1.25    ASH   NA                   
3   TEN YEAR VAR RET     1 s   1.25    ASH   NA                   
4   TEN YEAR VAR RET     1 s   1.25    ASH   NA                   
5   TEN YEAR VAR RET     1 s   1.25    ASH   NA
```

I need to repeat a block of rows a number of times (different number for different blocks). So I have a stand (STAND) and 5*2 plots in each stand. 5 plots are small (X = "s"), and another 5 are large (X = "L"). I need to duplicate rows for each large plot 20 times, and each small plot 500 times. So the condition for the block to be repeated would be something like this:

```
STAND == "TEN YEAR VAR RET", Plot1 == "1", X == "s"  * 500
STAND == "TEN YEAR VAR RET", Plot1 == "2", X == "s"  * 500 etc
```

And for the large plot if would be something like:

```
STAND == "TEN YEAR VAR RET", Plot1 == "1", X == "L"  * 20
STAND == "TEN YEAR VAR RET", Plot1 == "2", X == "L"  * 20 etc
```

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

We could create some numeric index of the rows

```
#row index with 's' value for X
i1 <- with(df1, which(STAND == "TEN YEAR VAR RET" & Plot1 %in%  c("1", "2")& X == "s"))
#row index for 'L' value for X
i2 <- with(df1, which(STAND == "TEN YEAR VAR RET" & Plot1 %in%  c("1", "2")& X == "L"))
#row index for those that doesn't belong to the above 2
i3 <- which(!seq_len(nrow(df1)) %in% c(i1, i2))
```

and then replicate the rows to expand the dataset

```
n1 <- 500
n2 <- 20
df2 <- df1[sort(c(rep(i1, each =  n1), i3, rep(i2, each = n2))),]
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution!  I tried it, but for some reason my Large plots were repeated 500 times. This is the exact code that I used:

Comment: @sashanikolaeva  It was based on your example and I am getting correct output.  If you look at `rep(i2, each = n2)` and 'i2' is based `X=="L"`

Comment: Yep, I checked the n-number and it all seemed correct. But I added other stands there as well so it looks like i1, i2, i4, i5 etc. i4 <- with(df1, which(STAND == "CONTROL" & Plot1 %in%  c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")& X == "s"))

Comment: When I check the number of rows in my original dataframe for large plots and multiply it by the number of repetitions (20), that number does not equal the number of rows that I get in the dataframe DF2. The number of rows in DF2 is much higher...

Comment: @sashanikolaeva  I am not sure i4, i5, etc.

Comment: I think I figured it out! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @sashanikolaeva  What was the problem?

Answer (score 1):

**data**

```
df <- read.table(text="
             STAND Plot1 X    DBH   Spec   HT
'TEN YEAR VAR RET'     1 s   1.25    ASH   NA                   
'TEN YEAR VAR RET'     2 s   1.25    ASH   NA                   
'TEN YEAR VAR RET'     2 L   1.25    ASH   NA                   
'TEN YEAR VAR RET'     1 s   1.25    ASH   NA                   
'TEN YEAR VAR RET'     3 L   1.25    ASH   NA                   
'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'     2 s   1.25    ASH   NA                   
'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'     3 s   1.25    ASH   NA                   
'TEN YEAR VAR RET'     2 s   1.25    ASH   NA",stringsAsFactors=F,header=T)
```

**Solution**

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(magrittr)

df %>%
  mutate(times=case_when(
    Plot1 == 1 ~ 2, # <- change values (and possibly condition) here
    Plot1 == 2 ~ 3, # <- and here
    TRUE ~ 1)) %>%
  group_by(times) %>%
  nest %$%
  map2_dfr(data,times,~.x[rep(seq(nrow(.x)),each=.y),])

# A tibble: 18 x 6
#               STAND Plot1     X   DBH  Spec    HT
#               <chr> <int> <chr> <dbl> <chr> <lgl>
#  1 TEN YEAR VAR RET     1     s  1.25   ASH    NA
#  2 TEN YEAR VAR RET     1     s  1.25   ASH    NA
#  3 TEN YEAR VAR RET     1     s  1.25   ASH    NA
#  4 TEN YEAR VAR RET     1     s  1.25   ASH    NA
#  5 TEN YEAR VAR RET     2     s  1.25   ASH    NA
#  6 TEN YEAR VAR RET     2     s  1.25   ASH    NA
#  7 TEN YEAR VAR RET     2     s  1.25   ASH    NA
#  8 TEN YEAR VAR RET     2     L  1.25   ASH    NA
#  9 TEN YEAR VAR RET     2     L  1.25   ASH    NA
# 10 TEN YEAR VAR RET     2     L  1.25   ASH    NA
# 11 AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA     2     s  1.25   ASH    NA
# 12 AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA     2     s  1.25   ASH    NA
# 13 AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA     2     s  1.25   ASH    NA
# 14 TEN YEAR VAR RET     2     s  1.25   ASH    NA
# 15 TEN YEAR VAR RET     2     s  1.25   ASH    NA
# 16 TEN YEAR VAR RET     2     s  1.25   ASH    NA
# 17 TEN YEAR VAR RET     3     L  1.25   ASH    NA
# 18 AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA     3     s  1.25   ASH    NA
```